# How to wait for response of fetch in async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

If I look in the console it is giving me:

```
coursesbody is: 
Promise { "pending" }
​
<state>: "pending"
```

```
const fetchCourses = async args => {
    await fetch(`/coursemanagement/getschoolcourse`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ schoolId: currentSchool2 }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(res =>{
      const body = res.json();
      console.log("coursesbody is:", body)
      return res.json()
    })
  };
```

What is the proper way to wait for the response. I have a hard time wrapping my head around await/async in js.

EDIT:
In useEffect I am now calling

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSchoolsCoursesDocents()
}
```

with setSchoolsCoursesDocents() being:

```
 const setSchoolsCoursesDocents = async () => {
    const schools= await fetchSchools();
    const courses = await fetchCourses(schools);
    const docents = await fetchDocents(courses);
  };
```

fetchSchools looks like:

```
const fetchSchools = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(`/coursemanagement/getschools`, {
      method: "GET"
    });
    const body = await result.json();
    setSchools(body);
    setCurrentSchool1(body[0].id)
    setCurrentSchool2(body[0].id)
  };
```

The state currentSchool2 is then used in:

```
 const fetchCourses = async args => {
    console.log("currentSchool2 is", currentSchool2)
    const result = await fetch(`/coursemanagement/getschoolcourse`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ schoolId: currentSchool2 }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
    const body = await result.json();
    setCourses(body);
    setCurrentCourse(body[0].courseId);
  };
```

However the console.log is undefined, but currentSchool2 should be set to 1 by the first fetch

Comment: `res.json()` returns a promise. You need to await it to get the result. You are logging it directly and that's why you see `Promise { pending }`

Comment: you need to pass the required data as arguments instead of using state variable which will be updated asynchronously and will not provide updated values at the time of consumption.

Comment: Yes, thank you that works. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do async await

```js
const fetchCourses = async args => {
    const res = await fetch(`/coursemanagement/getschoolcourse`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ schoolId: currentSchool2 }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
    const body = await res.json();
    console.log("coursesbody is:", body)
    return body;
  };

  // here is how you call this function
  const data = await fetchCourses();

// If you have multiple functions and data from one function is being used in second and so on then you can do something like
  const schools= await getSchools();
  const courses = await getCourses(schools);
  const docents = await fetchDocents(courses);
```

Comment: Thank you, and how could I concatenate multiple functions, so that the second one waits for the first one to finish and so on? Like: fetchSchools().then(() => fetchCourses()).then(() => fetchDocents()); I need that since I am storing the result of the first fetch which is needed by the second fetch.

Comment: @leabum I updated the answer to address this comment

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that I am working in react and it is telling me that await can not be used outside of an async function. I am calling the functions like getSchools() inside useEffect.

Comment: yeah, you need to create an async function outside that useEffect and call that function from within useEffect. Or you can declare and call the function inside useEffect callback

Comment: I created ```const setSchoolsCoursesDocents = async () => {
    const schools= await fetchSchools();
    const courses = await fetchCourses(schools);
    const docents = await fetchDocents(courses);
  };``` which I am calling in my useEffect now. In fetchSchools() I am setting ```setCurrentSchool2(body[0].id)``` but if I ```console.log("currentSchool2 is", currentSchool2)``` inside of fetchCourses() it gives me undefined, which is causing problems. I think the order of execution is still off. currentSchool2 being a state.

Comment: See above: I am not supposed to use states here